# Apple pay development server offline

Tags: ios, applepay

Since yesterday, 5/10/2017 ~2pm CST, the development server for testing apple pay transactions has gone down. The system status page for Apple Developer (handy link here -> https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) says it's up, but any request my code makes to **apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com** is returning a server not responding message.

I've also been testing pinging the server with this command, and all the packets are lost

`ping apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com`

Has the IP been changed? Or has no one else been testing transactions to even notice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed here, https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/‌, you must be logged into your sandbox account. Since I was not, the url my code was requesting was production (and not staging). By logging into my sandbox account, I was able to communicate with Apple's servers successfully